# Logging from Python not generating log file in Docker

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose

I'm using Logging in Python but when I run my python code in a Docker container no log file is generated after execution in my working folder. I guess that, because of using Docker, it is generated somewhere else but, How can I retrieve it? Or how can I make it be dumped in my working folder?

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, so if you've configured your application to write logs to a file, it will be in the container-private filesystem.  If you set the logging configuration to write to stdout instead, the logs can be retrieved with `docker logs`.